# error adding a splash to my expo react native app

Tags: react-native, react-redux, expo

I have my next splash, my idea is to be able to show my app logo when opening the application and then go to the start of the application, it works fine:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Image, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

export default class Splash extends React.Component {
    
    
    goToScreen(routeName){
        const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
            index: 0,
            actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: routeName })],
        });
        this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
    }   
    
    /*goToScreen(routeName){
        this.props.navigation.navigate(routeName)
    }*/

    componentDidMount(){
        setTimeout( () => {
            this.goToScreen('Home')
        }, 2000, this)
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Image source={{uri: 'https://i.imgur.com/r0jUwOD.png'}} style={{width: 250, height: 250}} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#33B747',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
});
```

The problem is the location of the splash, since in this way if it shows me, but it creates a lower button called Splash, on the other hand the splash when loading is shown in conjunction with the lower buttons and that should not happen, the splash must display only in full screen and not create a button.

AppNavigator.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { MaterialIcons, MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

import Splash from '../screens/Splash';
import NewsListScreen from '../screens/NewsListScreen';
import NewsItemScreen from '../screens/NewsItemScreen';


const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Splash: {
        screen: Splash,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerShown: false,
        }
    },
    News: {
        screen: NewsListScreen
    },
    Root: {
        screen: BottomTabNavigator,
    },
    NewsItem: {
        screen: NewsItemScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerTitle: 'News Item'
        }
    },
    },{
        initialRouteName: 'Splash'
});

const BottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: StackNavigator,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: () => <MaterialIcons name="home" size={24} />
        }
    },
    News: {
        screen: StackNavigator,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: () => <MaterialCommunityIcons name="newspaper-variant-outline" size={24} />
        }
    }
})

export default createAppContainer(BottomTabNavigator);
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import AppNavigator from './app/resources/navigation/AppNavigator';
import ReduxStore from './app/resources/redux/ReduxStore';

export default function App() {
    return (
        <Provider store={ReduxStore}>
            <AppNavigator />
        </Provider>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});
```

Attached capture of the error upload in `imgur` [capture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ff3SC.png) and [capture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxl7s.png)

Comment: @MuhammadNuman If I did friend, but it doesn't work, it's still like the capture one of the attached image in my question.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way to add a splash screen to an expo managed app can be found [here](https://docs.expo.io/tutorial/configuration/#splash-screen).

I've managed to create an `expo` project and achieve the exact same behavior that you've looking for.

I've used `react-navigation 4.x.x`

This is how it looks and you can find the [full code here](https://github.com/erandakarachchi/expo-react-navigation-v4)

[image]

Here is the code I've used.

`Splash.js`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, SafeAreaView, View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from "react-navigation";

export class Splash extends Component {
  goToScreen(routeName) {
    const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: routeName })],
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(
      () => {
        this.goToScreen("Root");
      },
      2000,
      this
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.text}> Splash Screen </Text>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#efef21",
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 22,
  },
});

export default Splash;
```

`Navigator.js`

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import Home from "./Home";
import Splash from "./Splash";
import TabNavigator from "./BottomTabNavigator";

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Splash: {
      screen: Splash,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerShown: false,
      },
    },
    Root: {
      screen: TabNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerShown: false,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Splash",
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

`BottomTabNavigator.js`

```
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-tabs";
import Home from "./Home";
import News from "./News";

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Home",
    },
  },
  News: {
    screen: News,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "News",
    },
  },
});

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

Also, I've achieved the same behavior using `react-navigation 5.x.x`

You can find my code [here](https://github.com/erandakarachchi/react-navigation-v5-stack-navigator)

[image: Navigation demo]

**Edit 01**

If you want to have the headers, You need to use a `Stack Navigator` for each tab.

[image]

Here is the updated code of `BottomTabNAvigator.js`

```
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-tabs";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import Home from "./Home";
import News from "./News";

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: Home,
});

const NewsStack = createStackNavigator({
  News: News,
});

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: "Home",
      title: "Home",
    },
  },
  News: {
    screen: NewsStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "News",
    },
  },
});

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226760/discussion-on-answer-by-emkarachchi-error-adding-a-splash-to-my-expo-react-nativ).

Answer (score 1):

You have used `Splash: {screen: Splash},` in your `BottomTabNavigator` so obviously it will add splash as on bottom navigator.
Remove `Splash: {screen: Splash},` from `BottomTabNavigator` and paste it on `StackNavigator` and set splash as initialRouteName

```
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    News: {
        screen: NewsListScreen
    },
    Splash: {screen: Splash},
    NewsItem: {
        screen: NewsItemScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerTitle: 'News Item'
        }
    },
},
   {
       initialRouteName : 'Splash'
    });
```

Comment: Hi @Rahul are you sure this should go like this `{
       initialRouteName : 'Splash'
    }` because the editor marks me an error?

Comment: Error in this part `{
       initialRouteName : 'Splash'
    }` friend

Comment: Yes, just in case if you need reference, have a look - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46684007/react-native-stacknavigator-initialroutename

Comment: I missed out an }, just a second let me edit the answer

Comment: No friend, it doesn't solve the problem either, the Splash remains active, that Splash is as if it were a loading, it should not remain, only when the application is opened, for the moment it looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/JGUQvhP.png

Comment: @Valentina you might need to bind `goToScreen `  with the class.
Try adding `this. goToScreen = this. goToScreen.bind(this);` in the class `constructor`.

Comment: @emkarachchi I am new to react native, I do not understand everything very well, I have achieved a lot thanks to the knowledge of other programming languages, I would like a more detailed answer with the example you comment :)

Answer (score 1):

you have to move splash screen to `StackNavigator` and add `BottomTabNavigator` into `StackNavigator` as a screen like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 

import Splash from '../screens/Splash';
import NewsListScreen from '../screens/NewsListScreen';
import NewsItemScreen from '../screens/NewsItemScreen';


const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Splash: {
        screen: Splash
    },
    Home: {
        screen: BottomTabNavigator
    },
    News: {
        screen: NewsListScreen
    },
    NewsItem: {
        screen: NewsItemScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerTitle: 'News Item'
        }
    }
},
{
    initialRouteName: "Splash",
});

const BottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: StackNavigator,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: () => <MaterialIcons name="home" size={24} />
        }
    }
})

export default createAppContainer(StackNavigator);
```

Comment: Error: `Error: The component for route 'Home' must be a React component. For example:

import MyScreen from './MyScreen';
...
Home: MyScreen,
}

You can also use a navigator:

import MyNavigator from './MyNavigator';
...
Home: MyNavigator,
}`

Comment: @Valentina you should import screen with a file extension like this `import MyScreen from './MyScreen.js';`

Comment: but that file does not exist in my directory, that is giving it as an example I think.

Comment: then you have to import your screen with file extension because I also faced this type of problem I resolved with import file name extension