# Error in viewing item detail and TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined - Expo React Native

Tags: react-native, react-redux, expo

When trying to access the detail of the article, it prints the following error message, adding these lines of code:

```
  13 | return (
  14 |  <View>
  15 |      <View>
> 16 |          <Text>{article.title}</Text>
     | ^  17 |      </View>
  18 |  </View>
  19 | )
```

List of articles NewsListScreen.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import * as NewsAction from '../redux/actions/NewsAction';

import Card from '../components/Card';

const NewsListScreen = props => {
    
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(NewsAction.fetchArticles())
    }, [dispatch]);

    const articles = useSelector(state => state.news.articles);
    console.log(articles);  
    
    return (
        <FlatList
            data={articles}
            keyExtractor={item => item.url}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
                <Card navigation={props.navigation}
                    title={item.title}
                    description={item.description}
                    image={item.urlToImage}
                    url={item.url}
                />
            )}
        />
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
});

export default NewsListScreen;
```

Print item detail NewsItemScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Platform, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const NewsItemScreen = props => {

    const articleUrl = props.navigation.getParam('articleUrl');
    //console.log(articleUrl);

    const article = useSelector(state => state.news.articles.find(article => article.url === articleUrl));
    //console.log(article);

    return (
        <View>
            <View>
                <Text>{article.title}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
});

export default NewsItemScreen;
```

When I replace this `<Text>{article.title}</Text>` with `<Text>Hello!</Text>` it shows the screen printing `Hello!` with no error.

These articles are the ones that are listed and the ones that are shown in the console correctly, the same ones that I try to see the complete detail, but I get the error message already mentioned.

```
author: "Megan Rose Dickey"
content: "Hellllooooo, 2021! Welcome back to Human Capital, a weekly newsletter that details the latest in the realms of labor, and diversity and inclusion.
↵Not a ton happened this week so I figured Id use th… [+6204 chars]"
description: "Hellllooooo, 2021! Welcome back to Human Capital, a weekly newsletter that details the latest in the realms of labor, and diversity and inclusion. Not a ton happened this week so I figured I’d use the time to look back on some of the more notable labor storie…"
publishedAt: "2021-01-02T20:00:52Z"
source:
id: "techcrunch"
name: "TechCrunch"
__proto__: Object
title: "Human Capital: The biggest labor stories of 2020"
url: "https://techcrunch.com/2021/01/02/human-capital-the-biggest-labor-stories-of-2020/"
urlToImage: "https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/GettyImages-1142216084.jpg?w=601"
```

Code Proyect: https://github.com/Publisere/app-news-react

> Note: It should be noted that the data does exist, it is not empty data.

Comment: Can you display the full error message please?

Comment: @HichamELBSI That is the full message as well as the title of my question friend

Answer (score 0):

Ok well...it seems that `article` is not defined .

The first time this component is rendered, Article is undefined so you just need to wait (or display a loader, empty page, I let you manage that) before rendering article data.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Platform, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const NewsItemScreen = props => {

    const articleUrl = props.navigation.getParam('articleUrl');

    const article = useSelector(state => state.news.articles.find(article => article.url === articleUrl));

    if (!article) return null; 

    return (
        <View>
            <View>
                <Text>{article.title}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
});

export default NewsItemScreen;
```

Comment: This does not solve my problem friend, because this data does exist, it is not empty and, that way it does not show me the detail of the article.

Comment: Well, how can the data exist if article is undefined? I'm curious, friend

Comment: Before it worked without having to declare anything friend, but that was with my old code now with this new code from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65459927/error-adding-a-splash-to-my-expo-react-native-app/65516821?noredirect=1#comment115880832_65516821 stopped working.

Comment: Friend, I don't understand anything. Can you explain to me why you have an undefined error if you say that data exist at the first render actually? Step by step we will solve your problem if you want friend.

Comment: I don't know how to explain them, I did a course in skillshare and in the course they were never declared that way and it worked correctly just as it worked for me in my previous code but with the solution they gave me to implement a Splash it stopped working see the detail of the article.